# How can I animate an SVG line, using stroke-dasharray, so that it moves from right to left

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two SVG lines one on top of the other. I have made them both animate. See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgsLwvb0/1/

The top line works how I want it to but I would like the bottom line to move from right to left instead. What do i need to change in my code to make this work? Is it a CSS change or a HTML change?

This is the code I used:

HTML

```
<svg height="5" width="150">
    <line id="top" x1="2" y1="3" x2="150" y2="3" />
</svg>
<br>
<br>
<svg height="5" width="150">
    <line id="bottom" x1="2" y1="3" x2="150" y2="3" />
</svg>
```

CSS

```
#top {
    stroke: rgb(112,111,111);
    stroke-width:1;
    stroke-dasharray:150;
    stroke-dashoffset:150;
    -webkit-animation: dash-top 0.5s forwards;
}

#bottom {
    stroke: rgb(112,111,111);
    stroke-width:1;
    stroke-dasharray:150;
    stroke-dashoffset:150;
    -webkit-animation: dash-bottom 0.5s forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-top {
    to { stroke-dashoffset: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash-bottom {
    to { stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I have just realised the answer!!

Swap the x1 and x2 coordinates around in the HTML (of course..duh!)

```
<svg height="5" width="150">
<line id="top" x1="2" y1="3" x2="150" y2="3" />
</svg>
<br>
<br>
<svg height="5" width="150">
<line id="bottom" x1="150" y1="3" x2="2" y2="3" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Or you could have made the bottom animation start at 0 and go to 150 instead of as it is.